# Trabalhando com Factory

Tags: angularjs, funções, controller, angularjs-factorys

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para uma lanchonete, onde ela terá de cadastrar as cidades e dentro das cidades os bairros com seus devidos fretes, o problema está ocorrendo na primeira vez que ocorre o cadastro do primeiro bairro da cidade, pois ele segue toda a lógica e tenta recarregar a função `carregarBairros()` que está dentro de outro `controller`, como está apresentado abaixo:

codigo HTML

```
<div ng-hide="consultaativa" class="catalogo md-whiteframe-1dp col-md col-xs-12 col-sm-12 padding-zero" >

    <div  class="texto_catalogo" id="catalogo_{{cidade.cid_atd_id}}" style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <form name="bairroForm" >
            <div style="height:70px;" ng-model="box_alterar" ng-hide="hideAlterar" class="box_alt_bairros">
                <div layout-gt-sm="row" style="width:650px;">
                    <md-input-container flex ng-class="{'md-input-invalid': validaBairro.nomeinv}" >
                        <label>Bairro</label>
                        <input class="moeda" style="width: 300px;" ng-blur="validarBairro(1, validaBairro.nome)" ng-click="validarBairro(0, validaBairro.nome)" ng-keyup="validarBairro(0, validaBairro.nome)" type="text"  name="bairro" ng-model="validaBairro.nome" autofocus />
                        <div  class="error" ng-if="validaBairro.nomeinv" role="alert" multiple>
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">Preencha o campo Bairro</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container flex ng-class="{'md-input-invalid': validaFrete.freteinv}">
                        <label>Frete</label>
                        <input ng-model="validaFrete.frete" name="frete" ng-blur="validarFrete(1)" ng-click="validarFrete(0)" ng-keyup="validarFrete(0)" id="valor" mask-money style="width: 300px;padding: 0px;" type="text"/>
                        <div class="error" ng-if="validaFrete.freteinv" role="alert" multiple>
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">Preencha o campo Frete</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 teste padding-zero pull-right" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" class="pull-right" layout-wrap>
                    <md-button ng-click="cancelarAlteracao()" ng-if="alterar" class="md-raised md-warn pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        Cancelar
                    </md-button>

                    <md-button ng-click="validaForm(validaBairro.nome, cidade.cid_atd_id)" type="submit" ng-submit="validaForm(validaBairro.nome, cidade.cid_atd_id)" class="md-raised md-primary pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                        Salvar
                    </md-button>
                    <div class="label"></div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </form>


        <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>



$scope.validaForm = function (bairro, cidade) {
    var valor = $("#valor").val();
    if ($scope.validaBairro.nomeinv === false && $scope.validaFrete.freteinv === false && $scope.validaBairro.nome !== '' && valor !== '0,00' && valor !== '') {
        if ($scope.alterar === false) {
            $scope.adicionarBairro(bairro, cidade, valor);
        } else {
            $scope.updateBairro($scope.id_bairro, cidade, bairro, valor);
        }
        $scope.validaBairro.nomeinv = false;
        $scope.validaFrete.freteinv = false;
    } else {
        $scope.validarBairro(1, bairro);
        $scope.validarFrete(1);
    }
};

$scope.adicionarBairro = function (bairro, cidade, valor) {
    $http.post(url_sistema + 'mostrarcidades/cadastrar_bairro', {'nome': bairro, 'cidade': cidade}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        delete $scope.bairro; // se nao colocar esta linha, quando alterar o campo ele altera o dado da tabela tambem
        if (data < 1) {
            $http.post(url_sistema + 'mostrarcidades/cadastrar_frete', {'nome': bairro, 'cidade': cidade, 'valor': valor}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                delete $scope.bairro;
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            $mdToast.show(
                    $mdToast.simple()
                    .content('Cadastrado com sucesso!')
                    .theme("success-toast")
                    .position("top right")
                    .hideDelay(2000)
                    );
            Scopes.get('mostrarCidadesCtrl').carregarBairros(valor, cidade);
            carregarFretes(cidade);
            $scope.cancelarAlteracao();
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.selectedIndex = 0;

            }, 10000);
        } else {
            $mdDialog.show(
                    $mdDialog.alert()
                    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                    .title('O bairro informado já está cadastrado!')
                    .ariaLabel('Existe!')
                    .ok('ok')
                    .targetEvent(event)).then(function () {
            });
        }
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

});

---

```
$scope.carregarBairros = function (id_frete, id_cidade) {
    $http.post(url_sistema + 'mostrarcidades/listar_bairros', {'id_frete': id_frete, 'id_cidade': id_cidade}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.bairros = data;
        console.log(id_cidade);
        if ($scope.bairros.length === 0) {
            $scope.ativo = true;
        } else {
            $scope.ativo = false;
        }
        $timeout(function () {
            Scopes.get('fretesCtrl').bairro(id_cidade);
        }, 3000);
    }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

});

---

print depois de clicar em salvar

[image: print depois de clicar em salvar]

---

print depois de ter pressionado o F5

[image: print depois de ter pressionado o F5]

Comment: Você não precisa inserir todo o seu `source code` aqui. Poste apenas o código referente ao problema, as funções que envolvem o problema que você está enfrentando. É mais fácil de identificar do que termos que ler todo o seu código só para procurar as funções relativas a ele.

Comment: Desculpe Celsom, não foi minha intenção, primeira vez que utilizo um fórum pra poder me ajudar, pode me ajudar com este problema?

Comment: Sim, sem problema, mas faça um resumo do seus códigos do angularjs, pois tem muita coisa ai. Deixe apenas as funções referente ao problema

Comment: Certo, ajustei para que fique melhor para entender, como solicitado

Comment: Mas ainda está difícil de entender.. Qual a função para salvar o novo bairro? Onde ela está?

Comment: ele chama a função validaForm, a partir desta função ele valida se está apto para adicionar o novo bairro ou não e chama a função adicionar se estiver apto.

Comment: Ok, mas amigo, edite sua pergunta e deixe APENAS os códigos relevantes para sua dúvida e problema. Ex.: não precisamos do seu código de `.run`, nem de definições de $scope que não tem ligação com a função para adicionar bairro, ou o seu factory, por exemplo. Limpe bem sua pergunta deixando apenas as funções relacionadas ao problema. Vai ser mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Melhorou Celsom?

Comment: Sim, vou analisar e já respondo =D

Comment: Agradecido, aguardo sua resposta :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, primeiramente, pelo que entendi, o seu problema é em executar a segunda função, visto que ela está em outro `controller`. Apesar de isso ser possível, já vou recomendar que você abandone este método!

A função do controller é apenas promover a comunicação entre o DOM e os Serviços (service, factory, directive, etc.. ). O controller, seguindo o guia de boas práticas, não deve ser usado para carregar dados, enviar dados.. Isso é trabalho dos `services`.

#### A solução mais fácil - mas não a melhor

Mova a função `$scope.carregarBairros` para o mesmo `controller` das outras funções.

//--- Fim ---\

#### A solução mais correta:

Mova as tarefas de requisição para um serviço (serice ou factory - factory é mais comum de se usar), vamos usar `factory`.

Dentro dela, você define as funções a serem executadas:

```
meuModulo.factory('factoryBairro', function($http) { //Não se esqueça de fazer a injeção das dependências aqui
    var service = {
        adicionarBairro:    _adicionarBairro
        /**
         * Adicione aqui somente as funções que podem ser chamadas por um controller, ou um arquivo externo.
         * Se a função a ser chamada, for chamada dentro deste mesmo arquivo, não há necessidade de definir aqui
         */
    };
    return service;

    function _adicionarBairro(bairro, cidade, valor) {
        //Toda a lógica para adicionar o bairro vai aqui;
    };

    function carregarBairros(id_frete, id_cidade) {
        //Toda a lógica para carregar o bairro vai aqui;
    };
});
```

Deste modo, você pode chamar os serviços de qualquer `controller`, basta injetar a `factory` como dependência e fazer a requisição, assim:

```
meuModulo.controller('Controller1',function($scope,factoryBairro,...){
```

E dentro do controller chamar a função dentro do factory:

```
$scope.validaForm = function (bairro, cidade) {
    var valor = $("#valor").val();
    if ( /*verificações aqui*/ ) {
        if ($scope.alterar === false) {
            factoryBairro.adicionarBairro(bairro, cidade, valor); //Aqui você chama o serviço
        } else {
            //Restante do código
```

Isso irá chamar a função `adicionarBairro()` que está dentro do factory, ela irá executar o $http, fazer as verificações, etc.. E quando você for chamar a função de carregar os bairros, apenas chama a função, sem mistério:

```
function adicionarBairro() {
    //Código anterior
    if (data < 1) {
        $http.post(url_sistema //.. restante do código
        //Mais código aqui

        //Substitua isso:
        Scopes.get('mostrarCidadesCtrl').carregarBairros(valor, cidade);

        //Por isso:
        carregarBairros(valor, cidade);

        //Restante do código
}
function carregarBairros(id_frete, id_cidade) {
    //Lógica da função aqui
}
```

Assim, sempre que você precisar executar essa função, faça a injeção do factory no controller, e depois chame ela.

Recomendo que você procure e leia bastante sobre isso. Vai ajudar MUITO o seu trabalho, melhorar a performance da aplicação, deixar o seu código mais limpo e organizado.

---

#### Editado:

Para obter um valor criado em uma factory dentro de um controller, para que você possa passar para a view, basta criar uma nova função, exemplo:

controller:

```
$scope.valor = factoryBairro.getData();
```

factory:

```
var service = {
    adicionarBairro:    _adicionarBairro,
    getData:            _getData
};
return service;

var minhaData = 'Cidade';

function _getData() {
    return minhaData;
};
```

**Obs.:** Se você deseja que o objeto mantenha uma sincronia entre o factory e o controller, ex.: Atualizou o factory -> Automaticamente atualiza o controller. Você deve utilizar o valor a ser passado dentro de uma array. Caso contrário, o valor não será atualizado até que o `$digest` rode.

Pelo menos eu desconheço outro método de sincronizar os dados. Caso alguém saiba, por favor, compartilhe.

Exemplo sincronizado:

```
var minhaData = {
    'valor';
};

function _getData() {
    return minhaData;
};

function _setData() { //exemplo
    $http.get......
    return minhaData.valor = [
        {id: 1, cidade: 'São Paulo'},
        {id: 2, cidade: 'Rio de Janeiro'},
        //etc...
    ]
};
```

Deste modo o seu controller fica em sincronia, pois você não reescreve todo o objeto, apenas um valor interno.

Comment: Vou tentar por aqui, qualquer dúvida posto nos comentários, obrigado até o momento :)

Comment: Celsom, ta funcionando super certo, apenas preciso de mais uma informação, como eu faria para atribuir as variáveis que eu crio em um factory para o controller em uso?

Comment: você pode usar um função igual as demais, apenas tenha um `return` para informar o valor. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: acho que entendi, no final de cada resposta, eu aplico um return com a variável certo?

Comment: como eu usaria essas functions para apresentar pra mim o valor do retorno em uma view?

Comment: Acho que estou parecendo meio burro, mas como informei acima, estou começando a mexer com angular agora, se puder explicar, agradeço

Comment: Veja que o `$scope.valor` executa uma função que retorna para o scope o valor atribuído dentro da factory. Consegue compreender? Se você for manter o uso dessa lógica, recomendo que leia mais sobre `factory` pois e extenso e dificil de explicar por aqui. Aqui tem um material excelente!!!! Veja: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb

Comment: @TalesBorn conseguiu resolver?